# Cloud synced notifications in Android L preview

Tags: android, push-notification, android-5.0-lollipop

In Android L Preview doc,

https://developer.android.com/preview/notifications.html

there is a mention of "Cloud-synced notifications - act on a notification on your Android tablet and it is also dismissed on your phone." but no detailed information on it.

Any idea where can I find more information about this and how to implement this new feature in my app ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with [User Notifications](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html), which is a feature of Google Cloud Messaging.

The idea is that your server registers a group of devices (identified by their GCM registration ID) that belong to the same user and gets a single notification ID for that user. Then you can send a GCM message to all the devices of that user using that single notification ID. This message can be sent either from your server to all devices of the user or from one device to the other devices of that user.

When one device handles the notification, you can send a GCM message to all the other devices belonging to the same user, to let them know the notification was viewed on one device, and the other devices would receive that message and dismiss the notification.

> To send an upstream (device-to-cloud) message, you must use the GoogleCloudMessaging API. Specifying a notification_key as the target for an upstream message allows a user on one device to send a message to other devices in the notification group—**for example, to dismiss a notification**. Here is an example that shows targeting a notification_key:

```
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.get(context);
String to = NOTIFICATION_KEY;
AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
String id = Integer.toString(msgId.incrementAndGet());
Bundle data = new Bundle();
data.putString("hello", "world");

gcm.send(to, id, data);
```

Comment: Hi Eran,Thanks for the response. Any idea how come this is Android  L's notification enhancement because it is GCM's feature,right?Also in the "User Notifications" page, it just stresses that its way to send notification to multiple devices with single identifier but no mention abt syncing, is that implicit?

Comment: @jayakarthik The synching is mentioned in the user notifications page as an example (see the bold quote in my answer). I'm not sure about Android L. Perhaps they are going to expand the current user notifications feature in Android L.